# How to implement your own "connect" function with Redux and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement my own custom way of passing props down to a component.

What I am trying to achieve is something similar to the `connect()(Component)` method, but with my own little twist.

Say I have a custom component, such as,

```
// presentationalComponent.js
const PresentationalComponent = ({
    name,
    loading,
}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            This component is: {name}. The current state is: {loading}
        </div>
    )
}
```

and an Error component, such as,

```
// error.js
const Error = ({errors}) => {
    return (
        errors.forEach(error => {
            <div>{error}</div>
        })
    )
}
```

I would want to wrap every component with a `morph` method, which would grab the requested state and also return a parent component.

So if I was to do,

```
const PresentationalComponent = ({ . . .
. . .
}

export default morph('layout', ['loading'])(PresentationalComponent)
```

I would want the `morph` method to return something like,

```
const getState = (reducer, values) =>
    // lodash
    _.pick(
        useSelector((state) => state[reducer]),
        values,
    )

const ParentContainer = ({Component, requestedState: {reducer, fields}}) => {
    const errors = useSelector(({ errors }) => errors)
    const state = getState(reducer, fields)
    if (errors.length) return <Error errors={errors} />

    return <Component state={state} />
}
```

But I'm not sure how to go about this, because hooks like `useSelector` can only be used in functional components. I'm not sure how `connect` from Redux makes it work.

Ideally, if I was to do,

```
const Home = ({ state }) => {
    <PresentationalComponent name='My presentational component!' />;
};
```

I would want to see `This component is: My presentational component!. The current state is: false`.

How can I achieve this with exporting my components such as `morph('reducer', ['state'])(Component)`?

I've tried something like,

```
const morph = (reducer, state) => (Component) => {
    console.log('reducer', reducer);
    console.log('state', state);
    return Component;
};

export default morph;
```

But that didn't work.